# jquery hide/show question

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list that looks like this:

```
<span id="contacts_tab_contacts_list_list"> 
                <li><span id="contact_35">John</span> 
                </li> 
                <li><span id="contact_36">Ron a</span> 
                </li> 
                <li><span id="contact_33">Ron b</span> 
                </li> 
                <li><span id="contact_34">35</span> 
                </li> 
                <li><span id="contact_39">33</span> 
                </li> 
                <li><span id="contact_37">66</span> 
                </li> 
                <li><span id="contact_38">77</span>
...
</span>
```

I have a `<input>` that I use to filter the list with `jQuery`.
I try to do it using these two `jQuery` lines:

```
$("#contacts_tab_contacts_list_list").children().hide();
$("#contacts_tab_contacts_list_list:contains('" + searchValue + "')").show();
```

So for example, typing `Ron` into the search box will make `contact_36` and `contact_33` be the only visible elements in the list.
the `hide()` part works. the `show()` doesn't.

What am I doing wrong? (Assume `searchValue` has the correct value, in this case `Ron`)

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try narrowing down the selection to the nested `span` elements:

```
$("#contacts_tab_contacts_list_list li span:contains('" + searchValue + "')").show();
```

Comment: Works Perfect! Tnx! I also understand the problem with my solution - I was showing the wrong object. But which objects were returned by 'contains'?

Comment: @Ben - The contains selector was only ever returning the `#contacts_tab_contacts_list_list` element :)